# Merging two dictionaries where items are interchanged

Tags: python, dictionary

Assume I've got the dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C' : 3}
dict2 = {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c' : 6}
```

[This](https://www.askpython.com/python/dictionary/merge-dictionaries) link suggest several ways to merge the two but all of the merges are simply concatenations. I want to merge them like a dealer shuffles cards, or like a zipper zips. What I mean by this is that once merging `dict1` and `dict2`, the resulting `dict3` should become

```
dict3 = {'A': 1, 'a': 4, 'B': 2, 'b': 5, 'C' : 3, 'c' : 6}
```

So the merge grabs elements from `dict1` and `dict2` in an alternating fashion. My dictionaries are in fact very large so doing it manually is not an option.

Comment: Just to check: Why do you need that specific ordering? While 3.7 did make insertion-ordered `dict`s a language-guarantee, it's fairly rarely you *rely* on it (among other things, the order isn't part of an equality check). Just making sure you don't have [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is round-robin [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) recipe to select data this way.

You can use:

```
dict3 = dict(roundrobin(dict1.items(), dict2.items()))
```

output:

```
{'A': 1, 'a': 4, 'B': 2, 'b': 5, 'C': 3, 'c': 6}
```

[recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

You can also use [`more-itertools.interleave`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave)

```
from more_itertools import interleave

dict(interleave(dict1.items(), dict2.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Indented for readability:

```py
from itertools import chain
dict(
    chain.from_iterable(
        zip(dict1.items(), dict2.items())
    )
)
```

If your dictionaries are not guaranteed to be of equal size, adapt this solution to use [`itertools.zip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) instead of basic `zip()`

Comment: It's an ugly adaptation to use `zip_longest` though, since you need to use a sentinel that can't possibly occur in the inputs (I typically use `sentinel = object()`) and explicitly exclude it from the values after the fact. The round robin recipe has the advantage of handling the uneven input case without adding that per item filtering check.

Comment: I suppose in this case it's not quite so bad; since you're using all two-`tuple`s (always truthy), the fill item can be `False` and you can just wrap the `chain.from_iterable` in `filter(None, ...)` without needing a special sentinel.

Comment: Exactly.  Or with a generator expression `(t for t in chain.from_iterable(...) if t is not None)`

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that could go wrong with this approach. What if your 2 dictionnaries don't have the same length? What if they have duplicate keys? What if later you need 3 dicts instead of 2?

Also, do you have a real use case behind this requirement? Do you really need to build a new dict with all data like this, or do you simply need to iterate over the (key, value) pairs in a specific, alternate fashion like this?

Assuming you don't have to worry about the above, if you only need to iterate, you could simply do something like that:

```py
def iter_zip(dict1, dict2):
    for i1, i2 in zip(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
        yield i1
        yield i2
   
dict1 = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C' : 3}
dict2 = {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c' : 6}

# you can then do
for key, val in iter_zip(dict1, dict2):
    do_something(key, val)
```

And if you really need to build a new dict, it is now as simple as:

```py
dict(iter_zip(dict1, dict2))
# {'A': 1, 'a': 4, 'B': 2, 'b': 5, 'C': 3, 'c': 6}
```

Comment: Correct, there is no need to worry of any about the above since the dictionaries will always be of equal size and there is a particular use case that forces me to alternate the elements like this. Thanks a lot for answer!